# IIS 7.5 - Possible to display friendly error if client connected with TLS version less than 1.2?

Tags: windows, ssl, iis

I would like to detect if a user is connecting to our IIS 7.5 server with TLS 1.0 or 1.1, and then redirect them to a friendly error message. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to do it at the application level (.Net MVC)?

Comment: I don't think this is possible on either IIS or application level. Negotiating the TLS cipher suits is done deep in IIS. It is up to the client to display a message if a common cipher can not be found. But I am not sure.

Comment: Only if you use a non-Windows solution, such as Cloudflare, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214770928-Legacy-Browser-Support